# Installing drupal core within aquia

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I understand aquia core is different from drupal core and that with testing it is best to install drupal core so when taken love there are no inconsistencies between the two... ? Anyway is it correct to install the drupal core in the aquia sites folder as if it were an aquia site? 
`localhost(aquia)/sites/drual_core_files/sites/my_new_site`

Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it the core is actually the same, Acquia includes some extra contributed and custom modules along with a custom install profile (see the '**/profiles/acquia**' and '**/profiles/acquia/modules**' folders). The core itself is exactly the same as the standard Drupal core with the same version.

If your site is built in Acquia then it may be dependant on some of the Acquia-contributed modules so I don't really see any value in testing it on a normal Drupal installation.

Answer (score 0):

I use Acquia Dev Desktop (formerly known as Acquia Stack aka "damp") (network.acquia.com/downloads/7.x) for all my local drupal development.  I never use Acquia's drupal. I always install my own drupal core.  I also have installed drupal "distributions" like OpenScholar, Drupal Commons and Open Atrium for use with Dev Desktop.  (Installing a Drupal distribution can be done with the process I outline below.)

Here's what you do:

- Download drupal 6 or 7 from drupal.org/project/drupal
- unpack the tarball in the Acquia "sites" directory
  Here you can see my drupal-6.22 folder at the same sites folder as my acquia-drupal folder

I don't have permission to upload images here, so they are on flickr:

[screen shot: sites folder](http://www.flickr.com/photos/15929201@N04/6215662698/in/photostream)

- Using the Dev Desktop application, goto: Settings > Sites > Import.  I select the drupal-6.22 core that I installed in sites by using the browse button to goto /Users/bwood/Sites, then highlighting the drupal-6.22 folder and clicking Choose.
- Fill out the import form like this:

[screen shot: import form](http://www.flickr.com/photos/15929201@N04/6215662848/in/photostream)

You can adjust those values like site01 has you get comfortable and create additional sites.* Click the Import button and Dev Desktop will open a new webpage for you showing your drupal site install page.
* Now follow the instructions to install your new site.

Enjoy!

You can adjust those values like site01 has you get comfortable and create additional sites.